# SELECT min row of each group in SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I've created a SQLITE table of four TEXT values, `first, last, street, state` and two INTEGER values, `age, weight`. I want to create a query that will SELECT the row of each `first, last, street, state` with lowest `age`, using `weight` for a tiebreaker if two entries have the same values for all of `first, last, street, state, age`.

I think I can do something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
GROUP BY first, last, street, state
ORDER BY age, weight
```

But I'm pretty sure the query I just gave you is going to pull an arbitrary row from each `first, last, street, state` group, then sort the results by `age, weight`. What do I need to do to determine which row of the GROUP BY is kept? I thought I might instead do

```
SELECT first, last, street, state, MIN(age), MIN(weight) FROM MyTable
GROUP BY first, last, street, state
```

But, of course, this would select the minimum age and the minimum weight, not the minimum age using weight as a tiebreaker.

SAMPLE INPUT:

```
first, last,    street,   state, age, weight
John   Doe      1 Elm     NY     50   120
John   Doe      1 Elm     NY     35   140
Mark   Knopfler 6 Strait  CT     67   130
Mary   West     32 E St   NJ     90   162
Mary   West     32 E St   NJ     55   120
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
first, last,    street,   state, age, weight
John   Doe      1 Elm     NY     35   140
Mark   Knopfler 6 Strait  CT     67   130
Mary   West     32 E St   NJ     55   120
```

I'd then like to go and delete the entries I didn't select in the original table, but I imagine that's going to be a whole new nightmare. (Basically, I want the table as if I'd created it with a UNIQUE(first, last, street, state) constraint in place and added rows by ascending age and ascending weight. That would produce an equivalent result.)

Comment: I think you need to show your sample data and expected output.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I added a sample; hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following may be suitable :-

```
-- Select SQL
SELECT rowid, first, street, state, age, weight 
FROM mytable AS mt1
WHERE (age * 1000 + weight) = (
    SELECT min(age * 1000 + weight) 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE first = mt1.first AND last = mt1.last AND street = mt1.street AND state = mt1.state
    ORDER BY (age,weight) ASC
    LIMIT 1
    )
```

- This combines the age and weight (but maintaining the individuality of each component for comparison hence multiplying the  age by 1000 (assumes highest weight would be under 1000, otherwise a larger number would be required))
- The were clause compares this value against the minimum such vale for the same first, last, street and state (no need for GROUP BY as the selected rows are all according to the group).

---

It's then a simple matter to utilise this to delete rows not in the SELECT by using (wrap the query in a WITH clause as a Common Table Expression (CTE) and to then use the CTE (cte1) to drive the DELETES to delete rows whose **rowid** is not in the extracted list of **rowid**'s):-

```
-- Delete SQL
WITH cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT rowid, first, street, state, age, weight 
        FROM mytable AS mt1
        WHERE (age * 1000 + weight) = (
            SELECT min(age * 1000 + weight) 
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE first = mt1.first AND last = mt1.last AND street = mt1.street AND state = mt1.state
            ORDER BY (age,weight)
            LIMIT 1
        )
    )
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT cte1.rowid FROM cte1)
;
```

- Note assumes that the table is not a WITHOUT ROWID table.

### Testing

The above was tested using the following :-

```
-- Load testing data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (first, last,    street,   state, age, weight);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
    ('John',   'Doe',      '1 Elm',     'NY',     50,   120),
    ('John',   'Doe',      '1 Elm',     'NY',     35,   140),
        ('John',   'Doe',      '1 Elm',     'NY',     35,   139),
    ('Mark',   'Knopfler', '6 Strait',  'CT',     67,   130),
    ('Mary',   'West',     '32 E St',   'NJ',     90,   88),
    ('Mary',   'West',     '32 E St',   'NJ',     55,   120), -- <<<<<<<<<< duplicated below
        ('Mary',   'West',     '32 E St',   'NJ',     55,   125),
        ('Mary',   'West',     '32 E St',   'NJ',     55,   124),
        ('Mary',   'West',     '32 E St',   'NJ',     55,   120), -- <<<<<<<<<< duplicate
        ('Mary',   'West',     '32 E St',   'NJ',     55,   121)
;
```

- Note it's unclear from the question if there should be any specififc action for duplicated lowest age as well as weight rows (see highlighted inserts above)

  - As it stands such duplicates will remain (could not exist if the combined columns were made a composite UNIQUE constraint)

.

```
-- Show table before deletion
SELECT * FROM mytable;

-- Select SQL (not needed as embedded in delete below)
SELECT rowid, first, street, state, age, weight 
FROM mytable AS mt1
WHERE (age * 1000 + weight) = (
    SELECT min(age * 1000 + weight) 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE first = mt1.first AND last = mt1.last AND street = mt1.street AND state = mt1.state
    ORDER BY (age,weight)
    LIMIT 1
    )
;

-- Delete SQL
WITH cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT rowid, first, street, state, age, weight 
        FROM mytable AS mt1
        WHERE (age * 1000 + weight) = (
            SELECT min(age * 1000 + weight) 
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE first = mt1.first AND last = mt1.last AND street = mt1.street AND state = mt1.state
            ORDER BY (age,weight)
            LIMIT 1
        )
    )
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT cte1.rowid FROM cte1)
;
 -- Result after deletion
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

### Results

The results of the above are :

#### Data as loaded

[image]

#### The select query

[image]

- Note highlighted rows duplicate rows that meet minimums

#### Data after deletion

[image]